# Laravel Blade - Chain/Embed multiple layouts

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

In my favorite templating frameworks they typically have the ability to nest layouts. Is this something that is possible in Blade?

For example...

## master.blade.php

```
<html>
  <head><!-- stuff --></head>
  <body>
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

## nav.blade.php

```
@extend('master')
<nav>
    <!-- nav content -->
</nav>
@yeild('content')
```

## breadcrumb.blade.php

```
@extend('nav')
<breadcrumb>
    <!-- breadcrumb content -->
</breadcrumb>
@yield('content')
```

## home.blade.php

```
@extend('nav')
@section('content')
    <home>
        <!-- content -->
    </home>
@endsection
```

## about.blade.php

```
@extend('breadcrumb')
@section('content')
    <about>
        <!-- content -->
    </about>
@endsection
```

The reason I love this format is that it makes it extremely elegant (IMO) to be able to choose your injection point!

- Have a one off landing page...reference master
- For the homepage...reference nav
- For any subpages (about/nav/product) reference breadcrumb

The layouts cascade and `'content'` gets rebuilt with the compiled `html` as it goes up the tree.

Is this possible? I'm hoping to avoid doing `@include` in the layouts as I personally find them cumbersome and a bit of an eye sore especially when you get to elements that are repeated often, but not everywhere (breadcrumbs).

EDIT: Based on answers.

Ideally `'content'` would be rebuilt and passed up the chain of nested layouts. i.e. If you have the homepage which references `nav.blade.php` the homepage content gets added to the nav layout and compiled. Then since the nav layout references `master.blade.php` the compiled layout would be passed up to `master` and built again. No duplicating of any content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot using `@parent`. Here's the example:

---

## `master.blade.php`

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{-- Stuff --}}
  </head>
  <body>
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### `nav.blade.php`

You need to put the `nav` inside `section` to tell `master` layout that this is a content. If you don't, `nav` will be in the top of `master` layout (yes, outside html).

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
  <nav>
    <p>nav content</p>
  </nav>
@endsection
```

---

#### `home.blade.php`

In this example, the `content` section is utilizing the `@parent` directive to append (rather than overwriting) content to the layout's sidebar. The `@parent` directive will be replaced by the content of the layout when the view is rendered.

```
@extends('nav')

@section('content')
  {{-- You can control where @parent should be rendered --}}
  @parent

  <home>
    <p>home content</p>
  </home>

  {{-- You can put your @parent here, give it a try --}}
@endsection
```

### `breadcrumb.blade.php`

```
@extends('nav')

@section('content')
  {{-- You can control where @parent should be rendered --}}
  @parent

  <breadcrumb>
    <p>breadcrumb content</p>
  </breadcrumb>

  {{-- You can put your @parent here, give it a try --}}
@endsection
```

### `about.blade.php`

```
@extends('breadcrumb')

@section('content')
  {{-- You can control where @parent should be rendered --}}
  @parent

  <about>
    <p>about content</p>
  </about>

  {{-- You can put your @parent here, give it a try --}}
@endsection
```

---

## Rendered:

### `home.blade.php`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <p>nav content</p>
  </nav>
  <home>
    <p>home content</p>
  </home>
</body>
</html>
```

### `about.blade.php`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <p>nav content</p>
  </nav>
  <breadcrumb>
    <p>breadcrumb content</p>
  </breadcrumb>
  <about>
    <p>about content</p>
  </about>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I get what you're after here. For instance in `home.blade.php` you extend "nav", which in turn extends "master", but both "master" and "nav" yield `content`, so the `<home>` content will render twice.

So, what is your expected output? I'm not sure "home" or "about" should really `extend` "nav" or "breadcrumb". I think of these two as sort of structural layout components, so it does make sense to me to `include` them in the master layout. In "nav" you can define a section to extend when your view needs a breadcrumb.

For instance:

**master.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head><!-- stuff --></head>
  <body>
    @include('nav')        
    @yield('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

**nav.blade.php**

```
<nav>
  <!-- nav content -->
  @yield('breadcrumb')
</nav>
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extend('master')

@section('content')
  <home>
    <!-- content -->
  </home>
@endsection
```

**about.blade.php**

```
@extend('master')

@section('breadcrumb')
  <breadcrumb>
    <!-- breadcrumb content -->
  </breadcrumb>
@endsection

@section('content')
  <about>
    <!-- content -->
  </about>
@endsection
```

Comment: I've added some content to the question. Does that help?

Comment: Also, the point of chaining layouts is to avoid repeating any markup. When layouts are chained and you are choosing the injection point of your content. The breadcrumb then just becomes a matter of using the breadcrumb layout and passing it a couple of values. There is absolutely no repeated markup...no conditional includes. Generally the master layout has three...maybe four `sections` at that point. `content`, `scripts`, `styles`, and possibly an `seo` content area.