# Laravel with blade - multiple inheritance

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I know there was many question like this one but I still can't handle with that problem. 
I have master layout where I put common elements for all subsites in my app.

```
(Inside common directory)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    @include('common.head')
</head>
<body>

<div id="l-wrap">
    @include('common.header')

    <article id="l-content">
        @yield('content')

        @include('common.dealer-area')
    </article>

    @include('common.footer')
    @include('common.cookies')
</div>
```

If I understand correctly: if I want elements 'stick' to master template I make include, these elements will be this same on every subpage.

Second blade inheritance after first one and looks like this:

```
(Inside homepage directory)
@extends('common.template')
@section('content')
    @yield('slider')
@endsection
```

And there is third blade which inheritance after second one:

```
@extends('home-page.template')
@section('slider')
<div class=slider> Some slider elements
</div>
@endsection
```

But view from third section doesn't show at all. I tried with @yield, @section...@endsection, or @section...@stop but it doesn't helped.

When I give second parameter in @yield function, after 'slider' in second blade:
   @yield('slider', 'some text')

It shows correctly so I think problem is the last one blade, the third one, do I use inheritence incorrectly?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184335/laravel-blade-chain-embed-multiple-layouts